# Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() error on php artisan optimize

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

when I run command `php artisan optimize`  this error appeares

```
Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()
```

Then I have to go to `\bootstrap\cache` directory and need to delete files then error disappear.
What is the issue how I could solve it?